# How to sum list

Tags: java

HI I want to print sum of Model.length. Now it prints the list of lengths. I want to sum them.

```
private void initializeVehicles() {
    vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
    vehicles.add(new Car("BMW", "X3"));
    vehicles.add(new Car("Audi", "A6" ));
    vehicles.add(new Car("Mercedes", "S 63 AMG"));
    vehicles.add(new Car("Fiat", "Panda"));
}

public void modelLetterCounter(){
int sum = 0;
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
        if (vehicle instanceof Car) {
            int p = vehicle.getModel().length();
            sum = +p;
        }
    } System.out.println("Suma znakow to: " + sum);
  }
```

The consol prints:

```
2
2
8
5
```

I want to sum it and get `17`.

Comment: You don't need to check instanceof. Vehicle will always be a Vehicle.

Comment: Your problem is ``sum = +p``. This doesn't do what you think it should do. It should be ''sum += p``.

Comment: Ok now i works should be 'sum += p' as u said. I have also others vehicles that's why i check. Thank you

Comment: *@NomadMaker You don't need to check instanceof. Vehicle will always be a Vehicle*. What if the OP had a Truck class and only wanted to sum the lengths of Car model names? All types of Vehicles could be in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable `sum` then add each `p` to it

```
public void modelLetterCounter() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
        if (vehicle instanceof Car) {
            int p = vehicle.getModel().length();
            sum += p;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: Now it prints only sum of two first.

Comment: @Mannual so the problem comes from `vehicles` list because the code works. Can you edit you initial post to share the EXACT code that outputs the list of ints you showed ?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the data I'm missing from your example, I guess you're looking something like this:

```
public void modelLetterCounter(){
  int sum = 0;
  for(Vehicle vehicle: vehicles){
      if(vehicle instanceof Car)
          sum += vehicle.getModel().length();

  }
  System.out.println(sum);
 
}
```

but your method seems odd to me. I don't know where vehicles list comes from in your function and second, you can actually make your method returns an int instead of printing it, and then decide what you want to do with it.

```
public int modelLetterCounter(List<Vehicles> vehicles){
  int sum = 0;
  for(Vehicle vehicle: vehicles){
      if(vehicle instanceof Car)
          sum += vehicle.getModel().length();

  }
  return sum;
 
}
```

An now call the function:

```
int res = modelLetterCounter(myListOfVehicles);
System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
vehicles.stream().mapToInt(car -> car.getModel().length()).sum()
```